# CollectionGroup Query returning an empty result

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I am working on an app that helps users search for their desired medication in nearby pharmacies then shows a list of the pharmacies that have the drug in stock with prices.

Here is the structure of the database:

```
Firestore-root
  |
  --- pharmacies (collection)
        |
        --- $pharmacyId (document)
               |
               --- medicine (sub-collection)
                     |
                     --- $medicineId
                           |
                           --- name: "Aspirin"
                           |
                           --- inStock: true
                           |
                           --- price: 500
```

I used to **CollectionGroup** query on **FireFoo** to get the pharmacies that have "Aspirin" in stock, for example, I got the promote for index creation and created the required index but the query result is empty.

Here is the query:

```
async function run() {
  const query = await db.collectionGroup("medicine")
    .where("name", "==", "Aspirin")
    .where("inStock", "==", "true")
    .get();
  return query;
}
```

Here are some images for clarification:

[Pharmacies collection with 2 Pharmacy documents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qpu7C.jpg)

[medicine subcollection inside the 1st pharmacy document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeG9m.jpg)

[medicine subcollection inside the 2nd pharmacy document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zilxw.jpg)

[CollectionGroup index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xYWy.jpg)

[Query Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wl9yU.jpg)

Comment: Yes its empty, when I was debugging on VS code it showed the size as 0 when I hovered over the query variable. @Alex's answer solved my problem though, it was a misuse of quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue in the following query:

```
async function run() {
  const query = await db.collectionGroup("medicine")
    .where("name", "==", "Aspirin")
    .where("inStock", "==", "true")
    .get();
  return query;
}
```

Lies in the second `.where()` call. In the database, your `inStock` field holds a boolean value while you are searching for documents that hold a string value, and this is not correct. To solve this, simply use:

```
async function run() {
  const query = await db.collectionGroup("medicine")
    .where("name", "==", "Aspirin")
    .where("inStock", "==", true) //No double quotes
    .get();
  return query;
}
```

Comment: The query now works, it returns the 2 documents under medicine. Thank you so much!!! I think I should add a field in each medicine doc with the name or id of the pharmacy so that I know which pharmacies to show as a result when the user searches

Comment: Good to hear that. You're very welcome, Maiz. Yes, you can definitely do that.